# error code 3 unknown method in android facebook app during post message on wall

Tags: android, facebook, json

Hello I am trying to post a message on wall, using this code.

```
             Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
             params.putString("message", "Facebook Dialogs are easy!");  
             AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
             mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(),null);
```

But i am getting this error.

```
Response: {"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method","request_args":[{"key":"message","value":"Facebook Dialogs are easy!"},{"key":"method","value":"POST"},{"key":"access_token","value":"AAAFby43GVwgBAJctMak5Y6IOaMylCWOFAXfXvsbMrckgZCi5wBZBSFWu02J1OY9ZB9aFLnwghHE72DgKe0YKIqctc5K54uyrA5mO5X2vQZDZD"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

Thanks bro..i tried this but still doesnt works

```
             AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
             mAsyncRunner.request("Message Test", new SampleUploadListener());
```

Here again i am getting error...

GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/Message      Test?access_token=AAAFby43GVwgBAJctMak5Y6IOaMylCWOFAXfXvsbMrckgZCi5wBZBSFWu02J1OY9ZB9aFLnwghHE72DgKe0YKIqctc5K54uyrA5mO5X2vQZDZD&format=json 02-13 16:42:36.027: V/webview(13218): ZoomScale 3 mPreserveZoom: false 02-13 16:42:37.085: D/Facebook-Example(13218): Response: 400 Bad Request

## Method Not Implemented

Invalid method in request

02-13 16:42:37.085: W/Facebook-Example(13218): JSON Error in response

Answer (score 0):

see following coding

```
public class UpdateStatusResultDialog extends Dialog    {      private Bundle values;
private TextView mOutput, mUsefulTip;
private Button mViewPostButton, mDeletePostButton;
private Activity activity;
private Handler mHandler;

public UpdateStatusResultDialog(Activity activity, String title, Bundle values) {
    super(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.values = values;
    setTitle(title);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    setContentView(R.layout.update_post_response);
    LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    params.height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

    mOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apiOutput);
    mOutput.setText(values.toString());

    mUsefulTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usefulTip);
    mUsefulTip.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    mViewPostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_post_button);
    mDeletePostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_post_button);
    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");

    mViewPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             * Source tag: view_post_tag
             */
            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
        }
    });
    mDeletePostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             * Source tag: delete_post_tag
             */
            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new Bundle(), "DELETE",
                    new WallPostDeleteListener(), null);
        }
    });
}

public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            setText(json.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            setText(activity.getString(R.string.exception) + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        setText(activity.getString(R.string.facebook_error) + error.getMessage());
    }
}

public class WallPostDeleteListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        if (response.equals("true")) {
            String message = "Wall Post deleted" + "\n";
            message += "Api Response: " + response;
            setText(message);
        } else {
            setText("wall post could not be deleted");
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        setText(activity.getString(R.string.facebook_error) + error.getMessage());
    }
}

public void setText(final String txt) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mOutput.setText(txt);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Hi bro...thanks for help..but still getting issue, i have edited the question.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples go to this link download whole program of Hackbook import it and see it contains all features link upload image or video or update status etc just have some error but comment them temp. it will work fine

Comment: That was awesome...wish i would have got the link in morning :(